# Stop the normal "double click" to open a word file from opening in the hidden code instance of word

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

My program: I use Excel to run all code. The main aim of the code is to produce a report (around 20k lines of code). Code can take around 20-30 mins to run (the running time is fine, as they can be 200 pages long). The report is produced into a word file by creating its own instance of word and starting a blank document. End users are running this (as and when they need to). Multiple different versions of office/windows are used across the company. Code created word instance is hidden to users.

My Issue: Since it takes a while to output, users sometimes need to load other word documents - whilst code is still running. This is where the problem lies, When you double click on a word file it opens in the hidden instance (the code instance) of word. This presents a multitude of problems:-

1. the user doesn't know where the file is open - subsequently opening it again or getting frustrated with the computer
2. It moves the cursor to the new document and continues to input the report onto the newly opened file.

Is there anyway to signify to word that my code instance of word is not to open any new files, and that new files should open in a new instance of word?

I have tried to have a look around for this but maybe I don't have the right terms. Any point in the right direction or assistance would be a great help.

Small snippets of code

```
Set oWord = New Word.Application
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste
oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeParagraph
```

Comment: Word, Outlook, and PowerPoint are not instantiable in the same way as Excel -- you can only have *one* instance of those processes running at any time AFAIK. For your problem #2, that should be handled by revising your code to properly scope the word `Selection` (or other objects) to the appropriate `Document` object, I think. If you're relying on `ActiveDocument`, that will be a problem. Even if you resolve this, I'm not sure if users will have any other problems since Word will constantly be receiving automation requests etc.

Comment: @DavidZemens I have added a couple of lines of code to the question. So just to be clear even though I have started an instance like above this does not actually do what I think it does? for example if I open any word files before running this code I can use the open document freely without interrupting the code instance. I can also run multiple report outputs without them interrupting each other (in new instances of Excel). I don't use the Activedocument tag but throughout code I reference word like the last 2 lines, I assume there is a better (more accurate) way to reference my document?

Comment: similar, yes you're using `ActiveWindow` instead of `Windows(_index_)`. If you can scope to the appropriate `Window` object, or you may be able to omit it entirely, like `oDoc.Selection.Paste`.

Comment: @DavidZemens Hmmm interesting, i'll try changing parts of the code to see if that helps with the cursor moving problem. I'll report back

Comment: The `oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeParagraph` also looks suspect, here you're referring to the instance of `Word.Application` class -- which can have 1 or more documents at any given time, 1 or more windows, etc., but only one window is the `ActiveWindow`.

Comment: @DavidZemens I assume that my index will always be "1"? since I create a new word and new document within that, or would it be better to read the index once the new document is created?. I assume every line of code that uses ActiveWindow I should really change to Windows(_INDEX_) to explicitly tell the code what window I want

Comment: Probably read the index after the document is created (if documents are already open, then Windows.Count > 1...), and then I wouldn't rely on that index remaining the same, just assign `Windows(Windows.Count)` to a variable representing a `Window` object, and use that object throughout -- that way if documents are closed or opened, re-indexing the collection won't be a problem.